# Why can't I find Firefox in Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, firefox-for-android

If I search for Firefox in the Android Market on my phone I can't find Firefox! How can I install it on my Phone??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you find it when you search at the [Market website](http://market.android.com)?

Comment: FWIW, the direct URL for it is: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Comment: What phone and OS do you have?

Comment: If you cannot find an app in the Market that means your device is not supported. You can still try to install if you get the APK and sideload the app, but it is likely to be a suboptimal experience (or even not work at all!!).

Answer (score 6):

Can you visit this link with your phone?

```
market://details?id=org.mozilla.firefox
```

Also you must note that: Firefox is available for Android phones (2.0 and above) and the Nokia N900.

The [official page of Firefox Mobile](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/platforms/) gives also a list of supported devices that have been tested.

Answer (score 4):

What model/OS/screen size do you have?

Firefox is not supported on all platforms. For example, I can get it on my Nook with Gingerbread, but can't find it on my Froyo Ideos with a tiny screen.